# The way to connect sliders is like a process

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I want to create sliders for levels, and there are many sliders created from 1 prefab slider, each slider is divided into different level markers, . The problem I encounter is that when completing a level, all sliders run,

Example slider 1 maxvalue = 1 with landmark = 5, the 2 maxvalue slider corresponds to 10 landmarks,
slider 1 runs 1/5 of the value corresponding to milestone 1. , slider 2 runs 1/10, etc.

I Just want slider 1 to run when the milestone is complete, slider 2 to run if slider 1 is full.

Please give me the solution, thank you very much !!

Comment: You can offset slider 2 value to slider 1 max value by subtracting it. Something like `slider2.Value = xx - slider1.MaxValue`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.